# How can I translate Array to Object in one line

Tags: javascript

[{type: 'fruit', value: 'apple'}, {type: 'meat', value: 'pig'}, {type: 'vegetable', value: 'carrot'}, {type: 'desert', value: 'cake'}];

=> {apple:true, pig:true, carrot:true, cake:true}

I wanna translate this Array to that Array with only one line.
I don't want to make empty Array to push. Help me

{apple:true, pig:true, carrot:true, cake:true}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interesting questions, you can solve using reduce like this:

```js
const myArray = [{type: 'fruit', value: 'apple'}, {type: 'meat', value: 'pig'}, {type: 'vegetable', value: 'carrot'}, {type: 'desert', value: 'cake'}]

const result = myArray.reduce((acu,cur)=>({...acu,[cur.value]:true}),{})
```

if you want to learn more about reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce